# Seminorm which is zero on dense subset

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $\hat{X}$ be a dense subset of $X$. If $p$ is a seminorm on $X$ such that $p(x) =0 $ for all $x \in \hat{X}$, does $p(x) =0$ for all $x\in X$ (is $p$ the trivial seminorm)? In other words, if $p$ is uniformly zero on a dense subset of $X$, is it zero for all $X$?
For instance, as a special case, are there any seminorms $p$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $p(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ but there exists $r$ such that $p(r) \ne 0$?
If the seminorm is continuous this follows immediately, but this is now always the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on whether $\hat{X}$ spans $X$ (in the algebraic sense, i.e. finite linear combinations).

If it does, then for every $x \in X$, we can write $x = a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_n x_n$ for some $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \hat{X}$ and some $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then if $p$ is any seminorm that vanishes on $\hat{X}$ we have
$$p(x) \le |a_1| p(x_1) + \dots + |a_n| p(x_n) = 0.$$

If $\hat{X}$ does not span $X$, by Zorn's lemma we can find a (necessarily discontinuous) nontrivial linear functional $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ that vanishes on $\hat{X}$.  Set $p(x) = |f(x)|$.

Note that if $X$ is finite dimensional, only the first case can happen, since all proper subspaces of a finite dimensional normed space are closed.  In particular your example with $X=\mathbb{R}$, $\hat{X}=\mathbb{Q}$ is impossible.

Comment: Thanks so much, I had the spanning case also proved but wasn’t sure if it didn’t span. Is it possible to construct such a functional if a Schauder basis exists for X? If every vector in the basis is in $\hat{X}$ then any finite linear combination will have be zero but in the limit this is necessarily not the case.

Comment: @Shash: Yes, the Zorn argument works in any vector space; no other structure matters, and in particular the topology plays no role. It will work as you say: since the functional need not be continuous, it does not have to vanish on infinite linear combinations of elements of $\hat{X}$.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear, I was wondering if there was an explicit method of constructing one of these. The mention of a Schauder basis was because I'd imagine its impossible for certain uncountable spaces

Comment: @Shash: I think that an explicit example will be impossible - that every "example" must use the axiom of choice in an essential way.  There are models of set theory in which the axiom of choice fails (but dependent choice still holds) and in which every linear functional on every Banach space is continuous.  In such a model I suspect one could also show that every seminorm on a Banach space is continuous.  I'd have to think about the details, though.

Comment: @Shash: Indeed, in the models I mentioned, every linear map from a Banach space to a normed space is continuous.  So if $p$ is any seminorm on $X$, let $E = \ker p$ and let $Y = X / E$, where $Y$ is equipped with the norm $\|x+E\|_Y = p(x)$.  We check this is well defined and is a norm.  Then the projection map $\pi : X \to Y$ is continuous, so $p(x) = \|\pi(x)\|_Y$ is continuous as well.  Therefore, in such a model, the second case cannot occur.